# Is there another method to make better animation on changing an element html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

I make some code to do a changing on an element HTML with setTimeout().

Is it possible to do other way to make more beautiful animation like the element appears slowly ?

I tied with setInterval(), I tried with fadeIn() but i don't know how to do with it.

```
var words= [' Web', ' Fullstack', ' Mobile', ' Php'];

var i = 0;

var word = document.getElementById("word");

function newWord(){
    word.innerHTML = words[i];

    if(i < words.length - 1){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("newWord()", 2000);

    }

    window.onload = function(){
        newWord();
    }
```

like this it's works, the word changes every 2s but I want some effects when the word is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transition to the text using CSS:

```
#word {
  transition: transition-length linear all;
}
```

This creates a transition for every style element that you change with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I find something works.

I just put this :

```
$('#word').fadeOut(2000, function(){ $('#word').fadeIn(2000);});
```

after else and it work pretty good.